# Create control with collection property

Tags: xaml, data-binding, controls, winui

I try to develop a simple DataGridView control. But I have an issue.

My column collection is not a part of the tree and the DataGridViewTextBlockColumn class "only" inherits from DependencyObject instead of FrameworkElement. So the binding doesn't work. What is the right way to make binding works?

```
<UserControl Name="UC">
<DataGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridItems}">
    <DataGridView.Columns>
        <DataGridViewTextBlockColumn Header="Name" Width="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=DataContext.GridWidth}" />
        <DataGridViewTextBlockColumn Header="Count" Width="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=DataContext.GridWidth}" />
    </DataGridView.Columns>
</DataGridView>
```

```
public class DataGridView : ListBox
{
...

public ObservableCollection<DataGridViewTextBlockColumn> Columns { get; } = new();

...
}
```

Comment: By **DataGridView**, you mean **DataGrid**?

Comment: No. I want to develop my own control. DataGrid from Community Toolkit is to slow to handle many data.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "the binding doesn't work"? At least, the binding target need to be a ``DependencyObject``.

Comment: Yes. DataGridViewTextBlockColumn is a DependencyObject and Width is a DependencyProperty but the Columns property of DataGridView is an ObservableCollection. So binding doesn't work. What can I do to make binding works?

Comment: You need to minimal reproducible code of your issue. Too much code makes harder to help. At least one ``DependencyObject`` and how you bind to it.